# exist function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i am using mongoose to create two models:
but when i try to create a new company and check if it already exist, it gives me an error say exists() is not a working function. Can someone help me out with this as i am new to mongoDB

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name:{
type: String,
required: true
}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


let shopSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    brandingDetails: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
    length: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    width: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

code for creating a new company:

```
module.exports.createCompany = (userDetails) => {
  return new Promise(function myFn(resolve, reject) {
    var companyData = new company();
    userDetails.name = userDetails.name.trim();

    companyData.exists(
      { name: userDetails.name },
      function returnData(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          reject(false);
        } else {
          if (result) {
            reject(false);
          } else {
            companyData.name = userDetails.name;
            companyData.save(function resultHandle(error, result) {
              if (error) {
                reject(false);
              } else {
                resolve(true);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

im getting this error

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\routes\routes.js:10:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)

TypeError: companyData.exists is not a function
    at myFn (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\src\user\userService.js:21:17)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.createCompany (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\src\user\userService.js:17:10)
    at createCompany (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\src\user\userController.js:11:36)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ashto\Desktop\FIT2095\App\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

can someone guide me on how to fix it? i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: `exists()` is a static method on the model class, not an instance method. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-exists

Comment: so in this case how do i perform a check, if something already exists in the database. Can you please help me out

Comment: Did you even bother looking at the documentation I linked? There are examples there

Comment: I'm sorry, i look at the documentation but id dont see the solution to my problem, i understand i cant use exist but i dont understand what to do?

Comment: You **can** use `exists()`. It would be `company.exists()` because `company` is your model class

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

```
module.exports.createCompany = (userDetails) => {
  return new Promise(function myFn(resolve, reject) {
    userDetails.name = userDetails.name.trim();

    company.exists({ name: userDetails.name }, (err, result) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(false);
      } else {
        if (result) {
          reject(false);
        } else {
          const newCompany = new company();
          newCompany.name = userDetails.name;
          newCompany.save(function resultHandle(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              reject(false);
            } else {
              resolve(true);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```